# How can I play Warcraft I on my Win7 Machine?

Tags: windows-7, warcraft, warcraft-2

I figure that I'd need to open a separate window, and run a DOS shell of some kind in it, but based on the trouble I am having with Starcraft I and my video card, which is a decent quality Nvidia bought so that Diablo III and Starcraft II run easily on it, what tweaks/adjustments can I make to screen resolution so that I can run Warcraft I (and for that matter Warcraft II BNE) in a window on this machine?  I have about given up trying to run most games of that vintage "as is" due to the deep differences in graphics and screen resolutions that attend.

Are there some kits/tools that will allow me to, in a windowed mode, to run Warcraft I and Warcraft II BNE so I can enjoy some silly nostalgia?

Comment: Warcraft you can just run under DOSBox. I don't know if Warcraft II Battle.net Edition supports windowed mode. It's a 32-bit Windows game so it doesn't require DOSBox and can't be run under it.

Comment: II BNE ... so, like SC I, I'd need to monkey about with screen resolution to get it to work?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It's not just screen resolution, unless you have a Windows 95 machine (which probably isn't the case, as you are running modern games).

Comment: Warcraft II BNE works on my 64-bit Windows 7 PC without having to "monkey about" with the screen resolution, and despite Kroltan's answer without having to use DOSBox. It plays in fullscreen mode, and I don't see anyway to change it to use windowed mode.

Answer (score -2):

For optimal results, *Warcraft: Orcs and Humans* and all versions of *Warcraft II* must be run on a DOS system. A lightweight and simple way to obtain such system is [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/), which emulates a DOS inside a window, as if you were running a computer of that age.

Simply install DOSBox, create a folder to store your game installations, and mount that folder (see DOSBox manual) as a drive (if I recall correctly, it is strongly recommended to use the C drive letter).

Then mount your game install media (probably a CD) as the D drive. Then navigate to the CD (in DOSBox) and execute the  `setup` or `install` files. Follow installation instructions, when it asks for soundcard, either autodetect or keep at default choice.

After that, you must navigate to your C drive (of DOSBox, not your computer's), and there will be a folder named after the game `warcraft` or  `war2`, not sure about Starcraft. Inside that folder there will be the `warcraft.exe` or `war2.exe` files. Run whichever you want to play the game.

If you do not have a copy of the games, you might want to look at user trade sites such as Ebay (or equivalent), because they are not being sold by Blizzard anymore.

Comment: "Warcraft: Orcs and Humans and all versions of Warcraft II must be run on a DOS system" **no. @RossRidge said** "Warcraft II BNE works on my 64-bit Windows 7 PC without having to "monkey about" with the screen resolution, and despite Kroltan's answer without having to use DOSBox. "

Comment: @ardaozkal BNE does support ["Operating System: Windows 95/Windows 98/Windows NT; Processor: Pentium 60 or equivalent"](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/warcraft-ii-battle-net-edition-system-requirements) Clearly if it works or not on newer systems is probably a hardware question. With DOSBox, you run the same environment as those old games expect, and so it's sure that it will work regardless of your actual PC specs. Regardless, the rest of my answer is still useful even if the initial premise is incorrect.